# remove characters from a string in a data frame

Tags: regex, r, gsub, grepl

I have a data frame where column "ID" has values like these:
1234567_GSM00298873
1238416_GSM90473673
98377829

In other words, some rows have 7 numbers followed by "_" followed by letters and numbers; other rows have just numbers

I want to remove the numbers and the underscore preceding the letters, without affecting the rows that have only number. I tried

```
dataframe$ID <- gsub("*_", "", dataframe$ID)
```

but that only removes the underscore. So I learned that * means zero or more. 
Is there a wildcard, and a repetition operator such that I can tell it to find the pattern "anything-seven-times-followed-by-_"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression syntax is incorrect. You have nothing preceding your repetition operator.

```
dataframe$ID <- gsub('[0-9]+_', '', dataframe$ID)
```

This matches any character of: `0` to `9` ( `1` or more times ) that is preceded by an underscore.

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/aZyfnU)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
 dataframe$ID <- gsub("[0-9]+_", "", dataframe$ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The link http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/Handouts/regex.html could helps you.

1. `"[0-9]*_"` will match numbers followed by '_'
2. `"[0-9]{7}_"` will match 7 numbers followed by '_'
3. `".{7}_"` will match 7 characters followed by '_'

Answer (score 0):

A different method.  If a string has an underscore, return from the underscore to the end of the string; if not, return the string.

```
ID <- c("1234567_GSM00298873", "1238416_GSM90473673", "98377829")
ifelse(grepl("_", ID), substr(x = ID, 9, nchar(ID)), ID)
```